# how to save and load tranformer models for further training and text generating? PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, save, transformer-model

please tell me how to save and load tranformer models for furher training?

I came across this blog post - https://wingedsheep.com/building-a-language-model

Here is the code from it - https://github.com/wingedsheep/transformer

I want to be able to save that model after some training to be able to fine-tune, train, and use it for text generation.

---

That's what the author of the post says about it:

**Once you trained the model, it is useful if you can save it, so you don't have to train a new model every time.**

To do this we add the following code to the LanguageModel class.

```py
def save_checkpoint(self, path):
    print(f'Saving checkpoint {path}')
    torch.save({
        'number_of_tokens': self.number_of_tokens,
        'max_sequence_length': self.max_sequence_length,
        'embedding_dimension': self.embedding_dimension,
        'number_of_layers': self.number_of_layers,
        'number_of_heads': self.number_of_heads,
        'feed_forward_dimension': self.feed_forward_dimension,
        'dropout_rate': self.dropout_rate,
        'model_state_dict': self.state_dict()
    }, path)

@staticmethod
def load_checkpoint(path) -> 'LanguageModel':
    checkpoint = torch.load(path)
    model = LanguageModel(
        number_of_tokens=checkpoint['number_of_tokens'],
        max_sequence_length=checkpoint['max_sequence_length'],
        embedding_dimension=checkpoint['embedding_dimension'],
        number_of_layers=checkpoint['number_of_layers'],
        number_of_heads=checkpoint['number_of_heads'],
        feed_forward_dimension=checkpoint['feed_forward_dimension'],
        dropout_rate=checkpoint['dropout_rate']
    )
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
    return model
```

Since we use the AutoregressiveWrapper as convenience class, we can give this wrapper the save and load methods too.

```py
def save_checkpoint(self, path):
    self.model.save_checkpoint(path)

@staticmethod
def load_checkpoint(path) -> 'AutoregressiveWrapper':
    model = LanguageModel.load_checkpoint(path)
    return AutoregressiveWrapper(model)
This makes it possible to easily save and load a trained model using.

model.save_checkpoint('./trained_model')
model = model.load_checkpoint('./trained_model')
```

---

**But this doesn't work quite well**

Script returns some error after it loaded created, trained and saved model, and trying to train it again.

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (257) must match the size of tensor b (256) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

I understand, it, maybe, but just a bit, that while training a model, we need to expand it by one singleton dimension, so if it had size of tensor == 256, it will be 257, and if we try to load 257 in our code, that wants to have a size of 256 - we will get an error.

```
input_tensor.size() = torch.Size([16, 257]), mask_tensor.size() = torch.Size([16, 257])
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (257) must match the size of tensor b (256) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

(+) If you will try the code yourself - it will be nice to run it on cuda. You can look guide how to do it with that code on part called "Running on GPU".

Maybe we need to save for example a .txt file with number of tensor size to make variables out of it, but I still don't know what to do... *Please help me figure it out...*

Answer (score 0):

Can you try loading the saved model with the following line?

```
model = AutoregressiveWrapper.load_checkpoint('./trained_model')
```

It might also be caused by an update in the code. If you saved your model, and then changed the code, it might not be possible to load it anymore. For example if you changed the size of the vocabulary.